# How to make an array to send the data to slave in AVR

Tags: c, microcontroller, avr, spi, master-slave

I'm working on an AVR to learn it. my code is working properly. mean it gave me the output same as I want but I want to modify the code. I made 4 functions to send the data to the slave. like as it's in the code I want to send `61,62,63,64`. but for these, I make `four functions`. Now I want to modify it as all the data send to the salve by `one function`. so my line of code will be reduced. second I want that once the 61 sends to the salve it prints something like `datatransfered` and once the `dataexchange` it's `display **exchanged**`. I tried to make the array and take numbers one by one but was unlucky.

```
#include <xc.h>
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <avr/interrupt.h>
#include <stdio.h>
void SPI0_init(void);
void LTCSelect(void);
void LTCDeselect(void);
uint8_t SPI0_exchangeData(uint8_t data);
uint8_t SPI1_exchangeData(uint8_t data1);
uint8_t SPI2_exchangeData(uint8_t data2);
uint8_t SPI3_exchangeData(uint8_t data3);
void SPI0_init(void){
PORTA.DIR |= PIN4_bm; /* Set MOSI pin direction to output (output to LTC2983) */
PORTA.DIR &= ~PIN5_bm; /* Set MISO pin direction to input (input form LTC2983) */
PORTA.DIR |= PIN6_bm; /* Set SCK pin direction to output (output to LTC2983) */
PORTA.DIR |= PIN7_bm; /* Set CS pin direction to output  (output to LTC2983) */
SPI0.CTRLA = SPI_CLK2X_bm /* Enable double-speed */
            | SPI_DORD_bm /* LSB is transmitted first */
            | SPI_ENABLE_bm /* Enable module */
            | SPI_MASTER_bm /* SPI module in Master mode */
            | SPI_PRESC_DIV16_gc; /* System Clock divided by 16 */}

uint8_t SPI0_exchangeData(uint8_t data){
SPI0.DATA = data;
while (!(SPI0.INTFLAGS & SPI_IF_bm))  /* waits until data is exchanged*/
{
    
}

return SPI0.DATA;}
uint8_t SPI1_exchangeData(uint8_t data1)
{
SPI0.DATA = data1;
while (!(SPI0.INTFLAGS & SPI_IF_bm))  /* waits until data is exchanged*/
{
    
}

return SPI0.DATA;}

uint8_t SPI2_exchangeData(uint8_t data2){
SPI0.DATA = data2;
while (!(SPI0.INTFLAGS & SPI_IF_bm))  /* waits until data is exchanged*/
{
    
}

return SPI0.DATA;}
uint8_t SPI3_exchangeData(uint8_t data3){
SPI0.DATA = data3;
while (!(SPI0.INTFLAGS & SPI_IF_bm))  /* waits until data is exchanged*/
{
    
}

return SPI0.DATA;}
void LTCSelect(void){
PORTA.OUT &= ~PIN7_bm; // Set SS pin value to LOW}
void LTCDeselect(void){
PORTA.OUT |= PIN7_bm; // Set SS pin value to HIGH}
int main(void){
uint8_t data = 61;
uint8_t data1 = 62;
uint8_t data2 = 63;
uint8_t data3 = 64;

SPI0_init();
while(1){
        
        LTCSelect();
        SPI0_exchangeData(data);
        SPI1_exchangeData(data1);
        SPI2_exchangeData(data2);
        SPI3_exchangeData(data3);
        LTCDeselect();
        }}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the first function. The others are just a copy, are the same and unnecessary.

```c
uint8_t SPI0_exchangeData(uint8_t data){
    SPI0.DATA = data;
    while (!(SPI0.INTFLAGS & SPI_IF_bm))  /* waits until data is exchanged*/
    {
    
    }

    return SPI0.DATA;
}
```

and in your main loop call the same function to send all your data:

```c
int main(void){
    uint8_t data = 61;
    uint8_t data1 = 62;
    uint8_t data2 = 63;
    uint8_t data3 = 64;

    SPI0_init();
    while(1){
        
        LTCSelect();
        SPI0_exchangeData(data);
        SPI0_exchangeData(data1);
        SPI0_exchangeData(data2);
        SPI0_exchangeData(data3);
        LTCDeselect();
    }
}
```

There you shuld have your numbers respectively in your slave device.

**Update for sending array**

```c
/**
 * Sends an uint8_t array to SPI0
 *
 * Here we send an array of uint8_t (aka unsigned char) to SPI0 one by one.
 * using the length parameter and an index variable.
 *
 * @param data a data array to send to SPI0.
 * @param length the length of the given array.
 * @returns nothing, but you can return any util info if you wish
 */
void sendArray(uint8_t data[], uint8_t length) {
    for(uint8_t i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        SPI0_exchangeData(data[i]);
    }
}


// Suppose we have an array named buffer
uint8_t buffer[] = { 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100 };

// Some where in the main loop we want to send it to the SPI0
int main(void) {
    //...
    while(1) {
        //...
        // We pass the array and its length in this way
        sendArray(buffer, sizeof(buffer));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Note that the array is defined and assigned statically. In real cases the arrays mostly used with a statically allocated memory, say 64 bytes i.e. `uint8_t buffer[64];`, but this does not mean that it will contain data in full capacity. Hence when the data is written to an array must be counted and stored in a variable to know the actual length of that array when needed.

Comment: okay. but how can i pass an array in this. like right now I have only 4 number it's good solution if I have more devices and more data.

Comment: Don't worry, it is easy I will update my answer for the array implementation.

Comment: and any possibilities to print something I tried printf but it's not working

Comment: Sure, post a seperate question about it, explain your problem well and let's see what is the issue.